# Get grads of parameters w.r.t a loss term in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, autograd

I my Pytorch training i use a composite loss function defined as :
[image].
In order to update the weights alpha and beta, i need to compute three values : [image] which are the the means of the gradients of the loss terms w.r.t to all the weights in the network.

Is there an efficient way to write it in pytorch ?

My training code look like :

```
for epoc in range(1, nb_epochs+1):
  #init
  optimizer_fo.zero_grad()
  #get the current loss
  loss_total = mynet_fo.loss(tensor_xy_dirichlet,g_boundaries_d,tensor_xy_inside,tensor_f_inter,tensor_xy_neuman,g_boundaries_n)
  #compute gradients
  loss_total.backward(retain_graph=True)
  #optimize
  optimizer_fo.step()
```

Where my .loss() function directly return the sum of the terms. I've thinking of make a second forward pass and call backward on each Loss term independently but it would be very expensive.

Comment: You want to compute the three gradients separately, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, and if it's possible without a new forward/backward pass !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### 1- Using `torch.autograd.grad`

You can get the different terms of your gradient only by back-propagating multiple times on your network. In order to avoid having to perform multiple inferences on your input, you can use the [`torch.autograd.grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.grad.html#torch.autograd.grad) utility function instead of doing a conventional backward pass `backward`. This means you won't pollute the gradients coming from the different terms.

Here is a minimal example that shows the basic idea:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(1, 10, requires_grad=True)
>>> lossA = x.pow(2).sum()
>>> lossB = x.mean()
```

Then perform one backward pass on each term out of place. You have to retain the graph on all calls but the last:

```
>>> gradA = torch.autograd.grad(lossA, x, retain_graph=True)
(tensor([[1.5810, 0.6684, 0.1467, 0.6618, 0.5067, 0.2368, 0.0971, 0.4533, 0.3511,
          1.9858]]),)

>>> gradB = torch.autograd.grad(lossB, x)
(tensor([[0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000,
          0.1000]]),)
```

This method has some limitations since you are receiving your parameters' gradient as a *tuple* which is not that convenient.

---

##### 2- Caching the results of `backward`

An alternative solution consists in caching the gradient after each successive `backward` call:

```
>>> lossA = x.pow(2).sum()
>>> lossB = x.mean()

>>> lossA.backward(retain_graph=True)
```

Store the gradient and clear the `.grad` attributes (don't forget to do so otherwise the gradient of `lossA` will pollute `gradB`. You will have to adapt this to the general case when handling multiple tensor parameters:

```
>>> x.gradA = x.grad
>>> x.grad = None
```

Backward pass on the next loss term:

```
>>> lossB.backward()
>>> x.gradB = x.grad
```

Then you can interact with each gradient term locally (*i.e.* on each parameter separately):

```
>>> x.gradA, x.gradB
(tensor([[1.5810, 0.6684, 0.1467, 0.6618, 0.5067, 0.2368, 0.0971, 0.4533, 0.3511,
          1.9858]]),
 tensor([[0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000,
          0.1000]]))
```

The latter method seems more practical.

---

This essentially comes down to *torch.autograd.grad* vs *torch.autograd.backward*, *i.e.* *out-of-place* vs *in-place*... and will ultimately depends on your needs. You can read more about these two functions [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148622/difference-between-autograd-grad-and-autograd-backward/69151578#69151578).

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get each loss component separately is to just define the loss outside your model (I assume now the loss is a method of your model since you're calling it as a method).

So you should change your code to look something like

```
ModelClass:
    def__init__(self):

    def forward(self):
       return output_of_the_model

# you can backpropagate inside the loss class directly 
LossClass(nn.Module):
    def__init__(self):

    def forward(self, model_output, target)
        loss_score_e = compute first component 
        loss_score_e.backward(retain_graph=True)
        # same for b and i components 
        return loss_score_e, loss_score_b, loss_score_i
```

Then the training script is basically the same

```
loss = LossClass()
for epoc in range(1, nb_epochs+1):
      #init
      optimizer_fo.zero_grad()
      #get the current loss
      loss_e, loss_b, loss_i = loss(tensor_xy_dirichlet,g_boundaries_d,tensor_xy_inside,tensor_f_inter,tensor_xy_neuman,g_boundaries_n)
      #optimize
      optimizer_fo.step()
```