# Gradient of neural-network using pytorch

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, gradient

Let's say i define a neural-network;  M : R^2 x [Net_params] --> R^2; y = M(x,theta)
I need a way to get the gradients evaluated at an specific input:  dM/dx|x=x_0 and dM/d_theta|x=x_0

I want to use PyTorch for the implementation

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2, 20, dtype=float),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(20, 20, dtype=float),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(20, 2, dtype=float)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear_relu_stack(x)

M = NeuralNetwork().to(device)
```

is there something like ~

```
input = torch.tensor([1,0])
y = M(input)
y.backward()
grad_input = input.grad
grad_params = y.params.grad
```

I'm aware the above code is garbage but I'm looking for something like this.

I tried to take the gradient of an network using backward, but this seems not to work, y needs to be some kind of scalar, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

By `dM/dx` and `dM/d_theta`, you probably mean `dy/dx` and `dy/d_theta`.

You need to backpropagate on scalar outputs, for example:

```
>>> y.mean().backward()
```

Then you will have access to `dy/d_in` where `in` is `(x, theta)`:

```
>>> input.grad
```

You can read more about backpropagation in PyTorch on [*this thread*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778401/meaning-of-grad-outputs-in-pytorchs-torch-autograd-grad/68781125#68781125).